# Website Hierarchy

Tags: html, file, hierarchy, directory

I've been working on a site for someone but I'm a bit confused how to set up the files and how to write the code for the pages in proper hierarchical format.

I sort of had it hard coded to a path

/WebsiteName/Pagefolder/Page.html

and I have to change the paths so that it is "in a relative directory structure" with index.html at the top and I guess a style folder with CSS and JS subfolders .

How do I fix this?

Right now I have something like

WebsiteFolder

- index.html
- style folder

  - css

    - web.css
  - js

    - table.js
- images

  - all the images are under here
- Page

  - Page.html

and there are about 8 pages.

so the path for a page is:
/WebsiteFolder/Page/Page.html

and when it calls the css file it is /WebsiteFolder/stylefolder/css/web.css

there was something mentioned about using a ../ method?

I'm just confused here

Comment: A quick googling yields http://www.thehelloworldprogram.com/web-development/creating-files-folder-structure-web-pages/

Comment: just for my own knowledge, are the ../ used to make it much simpler when you have to go back and edit the site? instead of recoding it all? And is having a separate folder the correct hierarchical way of organizing a site?

Comment: should I have under each page folder index.html as the main page?